# Restkit Mapping a NULL Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

First I have to say English is not my native language and probably my grammar is not correct,but I will do my best to explain what happened to my restkit.

I am learning **restkit** recently by myself,it is a really big topic and tough.

I am using this [api](http://www.raywenderlich.com/demos/weather_sample/weather.php?format=json).

I need try to fetch the value of **weatherDesc** in both 'current_condition' and 'weather'

Here is my code to mapping current_condition:

```
-(void)loadCurrentCondition{

  NSDictionary *queryParams = @{@"format": @"json"};
  [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/demos/weather_sample/weather.php" parameters:queryParams success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

 _myArr = mappingResult.array;
 [self Humidity];
} 
failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
 NSLog(@"The error is :%@",error);
}];   
}

-(void)Humidity{  
  restkitCurrentCondition *rkCC = [_myArr objectAtIndex:0];
   NSLog(@"///////////////////////the humidity is: %ld",rkCC.humidity.longValue);
  NSLog(@"//////////////////// the cloudcover is: %ld",rkCC.cloudcover.longValue);
  NSLog(@"/////////////// the weatherDesc is %@",rkCC.weatherDesc[0][@"value"]);
  NSLog(@"///////// the weatherDesc in weather is %@",rkCC.restkitweather.myweatherDesc[0][@"value"]);
  NSLog(@"///////// the weatherDesc in weather is %@",rkCC.restkitweather.myweatherDesc);

}

-(void)configureRestKit{


NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.raywenderlich.com"];
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

RKObjectMapping *currentMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[restkitCurrentCondition class]];
[currentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"cloudcover",@"humidity",@"weatherDesc"]];
[currentMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"current_condition" toKeyPath:@"current_condition" withMapping:currentMapping]];


RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:currentMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"/demos/weather_sample/weather.php" keyPath:@"data.current_condition" statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];




//weahter weatherDesc
RKObjectMapping *weatherMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[restKitWeather class]];
[weatherMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"weatherDesc": @"myweatherDesc"}];
[currentMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"weather" toKeyPath:@"weather" withMapping:weatherMapping]];
}
```

It goes not to bad, it said:

2014-07-15 12:14:26.702 myRestSample[10961:60b] ///////////////////////the humidity is: 59
2014-07-15 12:14:26.702 myRestSample[10961:60b] //////////////////// the cloudcover is: 16
2014-07-15 12:14:26.703 myRestSample[10961:60b] /////////////// the weatherDesc is Clear
2014-07-15 12:14:26.703 myRestSample[10961:60b] ///////// the weatherDesc in weather is (null)
2014-07-15 12:14:26.703 myRestSample[10961:60b] ///////// the weatherDesc in weather is (null)

Why did I get Null data?????????

I put these methods in viewdidload

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  [self configureRestKit];
  [self loadCurrentCondition];

}
```

I have a feeling that my keypath is wrong because weather is not included by current_condition and I don't know how to fix it.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing well and your English is very good!

Currently you are creating 2 different object managers and probably getting confused between then. You don't show all the code but you must be making 2 requests and I guess you are using `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:...` in both cases.

Note that `sharedManager` will always return the first manager instance that you created. So, you create and configure a second manager but you never use it.

Now, you don't need 2 managers. They both use the same base URL so you should just use one manager and add all your mappings to it. Now, you only need to make 1 request and all of the data you want will be extracted.

You will need to change the way you use the mapping result. Instead of using the `array`, use the `dictionary`. The keys in the dictionary are the key paths of the response descriptor so you can get exactly what you want from the dictionary.

Comment: I have already edited my question.You can check it again.I did make 2 requests.Let me see how to fix it

Comment: Give it a try and then update the question if you have more issues and we'll make some corrections. You're learning well and will learn better by trying.